# iPhone Modal view transition. Flip opposite way?

Tags: iphone

using the transition, [UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) seems to flip from **right to left** when initialized and **left to right** when returning.

Is there any way to make it flip the opposite way?

Answer (score 2):

Try this... transition the views first and when it completes, then present the modal view controller (not animated)

```
ModalViewController *modalViewController = [ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:modalViewController.view duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        [self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not if you're using the modalTransitionStyle property.

If you want to do it you'd probably have to animate it yourself.

[These](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStyle) are all the possible transition styles that you can use.